# Angular2 with ES6 - dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

app.module.js

```
AppModule.annotations = [
new NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: SOME_CONSTANT, useValue: 'whatever'}
    ]
})];
```

How can I inject **SOME_CONSTANT** to **SomeComponent** (some.component.js)?

```
SomeComponent.parameters = [
  [SOME_CONSTANT]
];
```

Doesn't work. What is obvious because how interpreter would know what `SOME_CONSTANT` is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it probably makes sense to use a service for this scenario and inject the service into SomeComponent's constructor:

**App Module**

```
AppModule.annotations = [
new NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  providers: [ConstantService]
})];
```

**Constant Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConstantService {
  SOME_CONSTANT = 'whatever';
}
```

**Some Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConstantService } from './constant.service';

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor SomeComponent(constants: ConstantService) {
    let someConstant = constants.SOME_CONSTANT;
  }
}
```